# Wireshark on macOS does not parse HTTP packets

Tags: macos, http, wireshark

I installed Wireshark on macOS High Sierra and captured some network trafic while making HTTP calls to a local server using CURL.
The traffic captured in wireshark only showed TCP packets. When looking at the data whitin the TCP packets I could see the HTTP packets, but these were not recognized by Wireshark as the packet protocol.

Any way to make it properly parse the HTTP packets?

Here's an example capture:
[image]

One guess I had was that Wireshark only recognises a packet as HTTP if it's on port 80. If this is so, is there any way to change this setting?

P.S. No HTTPS involved here, just plane old HTTP from a client to a REST API.

Comment: this is an useful question.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured out the issue.
My server was exposed on port 5000 (which is the default Flask port).
Turns out that port 5000 is conventionally used for IPA packets, which is a GSM over IP protocol. Wireshark aparently used the port number to determine the type of packet, and so it misclasified it as an IPA packet.

Once I moved my server to another port (e.g. 5001) - the problem was gone.

P.S. See https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/9240/data-which-has-been-sent-over-tcpip-has-been-recognized-by-wireshark-as-ipa-protocol for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement @MartanRubin's answer, it's also possible to indicate to WireShark that port 5000 is not GSM over IP. In *Edit → Preferences → Protocols → GSM over IP* remove port 5000 from the "TCP port(s)" field:

[image: wireshark preferences]

To persist the preference you also need to add 5000 to HTTP protocol "TCP port(s)" field. Then they survive restart (tested in a custom profile). Note however, that when you open GSM over IP protocol's preferences, 5000 is still there, but doesn't have effect. But when I save it (click OK button), my `/home/user/.config/wireshark/profiles/CustomProfile/decode_as_entries` gets messed up again, and I need to repeat the process on both protocol's "TCP port(s)" field. A counter-intuitive UI, I would say.